# Как разбить мои заказы на категории в личном кабинете (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Делаю магазин и нужно в личном кабинете, в "Мои заказы" сделать категории. На сайте есть 5 разных товаров и каждый под своей категорией. Нужно чтобы когда заходил в "мои заказы", я мог выбрать одну из категорий, например "Одежда" и мне показало все заказы из категории "Одежда". Я первый раз пользуюсь Woocommerce и не могу разобраться:( Вот код из файла `orders.php`)

```html
<?php
/**
 * Orders
 *
 * Shows orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

 


defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>



<?php if ( $has_orders ) : ?>

    <table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
                ?>
                <tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_status() ); ?> order">
                    <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number() ); ?>
                                </a>
                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                /* translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                                echo wp_kses_post( sprintf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ) );
                                ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );

                                if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                                    foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders_pagination' ); ?>

    <?php if ( 1 < $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-pagination woocommerce-pagination--without-numbers woocommerce-Pagination">
            <?php if ( 1 !== $current_page ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-button woocommerce-button--previous woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--previous button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $current_page - 1 ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Previous', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( intval( $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) !== $current_page ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-button woocommerce-button--next woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--next button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $current_page + 1 ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-message woocommerce-message--info woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
        <a class="woocommerce-Button button" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Browse products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'No order has been made yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>



<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>
```

Comment: Прекрати ставить тег `php` в вопросы по ВП, если не хочешь чтобы ПХП-исты их закрывали.

Comment: Тебе надо перебирать все заказы, разбивать их по категориям, далее выводить в своём виде. Если ты рассчитываешь на изменения 2-3 параметров или строк, то ничего не выйдет, надо перебирать все заказы и во время перебора у товара читать категорию. Кстати, не забудь, что один товар, может быть в нескольких категориях и это может стать затруднением.